# Считывание слов из строки

Tags: java

```
package homeWork5;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WarAndWorldService1 {
    public void runSet() {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("Module/Война и мир_книга.txt");
            Set<String> wordsWeNeed = new HashSet<>();
            int symbol;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((symbol = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
                if (symbol != ' ' && symbol != '\n' && symbol != ',' && symbol != '.' && symbol != '!' && symbol != ')' && symbol != '"'
                        && symbol != ':' && symbol != ';' && symbol != '?' && symbol != '*' && symbol != '(') {
                    builder.append((char) symbol);
                } else {
                    wordsWeNeed.add(builder.toString());
                    builder.setLength(0);
                }
            }
                wordsWeNeed.add(builder.toString());
                System.out.println(wordsWeNeed);
                System.out.println(wordsWeNeed.size());
            } catch(FileNotFoundException f){
                System.out.println("Ошибка. Файл не найден.");
            } catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Ошибка чтения файла.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос в том, каким образом я могу данные текстового файла сначала преобразовать в строку. Например:

```
while((symbol = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
builder.append((char) symbol);
}
String result = builder.toString;
```

А затем уже из этой строки извлекать слова (без знаков препинания и т.п.).
Понимаю, что есть что-то вроде вот этого:

```
 String[] resultArr = result.split(" ");
```

Но как я понимаю, в данном случае требуется использовать регулярные выражения.
И вопрос в том, могу ли я без регулярных выражений извлекать "чистые" слова из строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список слов действительно можно получить с помощью `split(" ")`. А избавиться от знаков препинания можно с помощью статического метода `Character.isLetterOrDigit`.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WarAndWorldService1 {
    
    public void runSet() throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("Module/Война и мир_книга.txt"))) {
            Set<String> result = lineStream
                    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")))
                    .map(this::process)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    private String process(String word) {
        return word.chars()
                .filter(Character::isLetterOrDigit)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString().trim();
    }

}
```